# Show datatable in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, devexpress

I wrote stored procedure, and I want to show result in gridview(ASPxGridView by DevExpress, but should be same way as GridView).

I get datatable, that's fine, but when I try to pass i to GridView, nothing happens.

Is there anything else I should do except this:

```
ASPxGridView1.DataSource = SP1;
ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
```

SP1 is datatable.

Comment: did you try AutoGenerateColumns = true? Also, in Which page event are you doing this? you have this code in the Page_Load Event.

Comment: please provide more code and it's corresponding eventHandler where you are calling .DataSource = SP1 and .DataBind();

Comment: Yes, tried in page load, and now with autogenerate true, still nothing.

Comment: And while you're at it, can you debug and post the values of ASPxGridView1.Rows.Count and ASPxGridView1.Visible?

Comment: Also .. are you sure that the StoredProc is executing properly and not return empty results...??

Comment: please share full page/ASPxGridView markup and code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the “SP1” DataTable object contains DataRows:

```
int rowCount = (SP1 as DataTable).Rows.Count;
```

In addition, check the following KB Article in the DX Support base:

**Why might paging (sorting, grouping, filtering) not work in the ASPxGridView?**

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18183.aspx

and the following Code Central example:

**Bind a grid to a DataTable via code**

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E168.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's all you need to do. If you are not seeing any data is either because your datatable is empty or you have some other bug somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Your user-defined function

```
private void GridLoad()
{
    ASPxGridView1.DataSource = SP1;
    ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Call this function in your `Page_Load` event

```
GridLoad();
```

If you still don't see the grid, map your `SP1` to a `Session` variable, and then call it like:

1. Bind your `DataTable` to a `Session` variable

   ```
   Session["myDatatable"]=SP1;
   ```
2. Issue this function on `Page_Load`:

   ```
   GridLoad();
   ```

Your user-defined function (outside of `Page_Load`)

```
private void GridLoad()
{
    if(Session["myDatatable"]==null)
    {
        ASPxGridView1.DataSource = SP1;
        ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ASPxGridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["myDatatable"];
        ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```